# Add 1 - Javascript Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android

Trying to make a "click counter" game in android studio.

```
int clicked = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked++;
            text.setText(clicked);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the code i set up for the counter. Any ideas about what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try: `@Override public void onClick(View v) { clicked+=1; text.setText(String.valueOf(clicked);
text.invalidate();}`

Comment: Btw.. How is invalidate(); doing anything to this?

Comment: No problem, just added it to remove all possible factors. Invalidate forces the view to redraw kind of refresh. You can also try it without it.